# Class and Struct as Projectables

Tags: c#, .net

Many a times i have to do select required fields from a class as in case of selected desired fields from Table in sql.
So i was thinking of making my class and struct as Projectables.

Here is what I want to achieve.

```
public class Email
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Cc { get; set; }
    public string Bcc { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }
}

public class EmailProjection
{
   // instead of this 

    //public string Subject { get; set; }
    //public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }

    // I want to do this
    Email.Project(Subject,ReceivedDate);
}

public class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var emailList = new List<Email>();
        /* populate  emails here from source*/

        // I want to do this
        List<EmailProjection> emailProjectionList = emailList.Project(EmailProjection).ToList();

        // rather than 
        List<EmailProjection> emailProjectionList= emailList.Select(email=>new {email.Subject,email.ReceivedDate}).ToList();}
    }
```

Can somebody help me as to how to go about this? Hints?? Is it achievable?

Comment: You could use T4 template to get the property code generated for you at build.

Comment: @ MarcinJuraszek, Thanks for the reply. One more tool to be aware of. Btw how to go about implementing my own projectable syntax as some kind of api. So it feels more natural and feels like it is sth that is built into the object and also get intellisense support.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at Automapper: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.
It is a library to map DTO based on naming conventions and rules.
Take a look in the wiki there is a [Projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection) page, that could be the one you are looking for.
Just for connect with your example, you can eventually write code like this:

```
Mapper.Map<EMail, EmailProjection>(yourObjects);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Was looking for this kind of tool. Btw how to go about implementing my own projectable syntax as some kind of api. So it feels more natural and feels like it is sth that is built into the object and also get intellisense support.